# How to extract the xml namespace value with apache camel

Tags: java, xpath

How can I extract the xmlns value, "abcdef" with xpath. I tried

/*[local-name()='Document']/@xmlns

but it doesn't work

`<Document xmlns="abcdef">`

Is this possible with camel routes